# QuickSort Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort

I copied a boilerplate code for quickSort which uses recursion to sort a randomised array. For some reason it keeps running into "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

```
function quickSort(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) { return arr }
    let pivot = arr[arr.length - 1]
    let left = []
    let right = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) { left.push(arr[i]) }
        else { right.push(arr[i]) }
    }
    return [...quickSort(left), pivot, ...quickSort(right)]
}
```

```
else { right.push(arr[i]) }
                     ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.push (<anonymous>)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:35:22)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)
    at quickSort (file:///D:/bsc/test.mjs:37:43)

Node.js v17.7.2
```

I tried retracing the steps of the code step by step but can't figrue out what is tripping up my code. Since it is boilerplate code I doubt it has something to do with logical error.

Comment: You're unconditionally calling `quickSort`, a recursive call needs to be conditioned.

Comment: If you "stepped through" you'd see this would never work - where did you get the "boiler plate"?

Comment: You need to exclude `pivot` from your left/right arrays, then it works fine: `if (arr[i] < pivot) { left.push(arr[i]) } else if (arr[i] > pivot) { right.push(arr[i]) }`, otherwise its included twice in the `return [ ..left, pivot, ..right]` - though that will also remove duplicates - easy enough to fix with a middle pivot array:  https://jsfiddle.net/ukemnx6o/

Comment: Still wondering where you got the "boiler plate code" - please provide a source link.

Comment: The recursive is conditioned to exit if the length of the array goes below 2. I was following a youtube video: https://youtu.be/lWLTHsQnHDI?t=167 , In the for loop  I noticed that it should have been "i < arr.length - 1" since my pivot is the last element of the array.

Comment: what if I wanted to keep the duplicates and exclude the pivot simultaneously

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {` would also exclude the pivot value and your code would work fine.  Always worth citing your sources, we could have had a quick look and pointed out the difference.

Comment: removing duplicates would help with memory but in some cases, we would lose data that could serve other purposes.

Comment: Can you update (or create a new question) with your current issue.  As asked, it's fixed as a typo because you put `i < arr.length` instead of the source material's `i < arr.length - 1` - this fixes the maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Answer (score 0):

`for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`The for loop did not take the last element i.e. the pivot into account which caused it to go into an infinite loop. By excluding the pivot from the loop the logic becomes complete.  `for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to know that the quickSort algorithm can take O(n^2) time in the worst-case scenario and O(n log n) time on average. By choosing the first or last element, you may put the algorithm in the worst-case time complexity scenario, so it is better to select a random element from the list as the pivot to achieve O(n log n) time complexity. Also, your mistake is that when you choose an element as the pivot, you do not remove it from your list, which leads the loop to repeat indefinitely, thus causing an infinite loop.

To write an optimized quickSort algorithm in JavaScript, you can use the following code:

```
function quickSort(list) {
  if (list.length < 2) return list
  const random = Math.ceil(list.length / 2)
  const pivot = list[random]
  let lower = []
  let greater = []
  // pivot element will be removed
  list = [...list.slice(0, random), ...list.slice(random + 1)]
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] > pivot) greater.push(list[i])
    else lower.push(list[i])
  }
  return [...quickSort(lower), pivot, ...quickSort(greater)]
}
```